# AWS S3 Java 2.X Create Bucket Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk-2.x

Create bucket is failing with **software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: An error occurred when parsing the HTTP request PUT at '/' (Service: S3, Status Code: 400, Request ID: )**

```
S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder()
            .endpointProvider(new S3EndpointProvider() {
                @Override
                public CompletableFuture<Endpoint> resolveEndpoint(S3EndpointParams endpointParams) {
                    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Endpoint.builder()
                            .url(URI.create("end point url"))
                            .build());
                }
            }).httpClient(UrlConnectionHttpClient.builder().build())
          
            .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
            .credentialsProvider(() -> AwsBasicCredentials.create(‘Access key ID’,”Secret Key”))
            
            .build();

    CreateBucketRequest bucketRequest = CreateBucketRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(“bucket name”)
                    .build(); 

     s3Client.createBucket(bucketRequest);
```

Find the complete stack trace of the error below :

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: An error occurred when parsing the HTTP request PUT at '/' (Service: S3, Status Code: 400, Request ID: )
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handleErrorResponse(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:156)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handleResponse(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:108)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handle(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:85)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handle(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:43)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler$Crc32ValidationResponseHandler.handle(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:93)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseClientHandler.lambda$successTransformationResponseHandler$7(BaseClientHandler.java:279)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:40)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:30)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:72)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:78)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:40)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.java:52)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.java:37)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:81)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:36)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:56)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:36)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:50)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:32)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:224)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:103)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.doExecute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:173)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.lambda$execute$1(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:80)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.measureApiCallSuccess(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:182)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:74)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:45)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:53)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3Client.createBucket(DefaultS3Client.java:1100)
    at s3.Client.createBucket(Client.java:119)
    at s3.Client.getS3Client(Client.java:54)
    at s3.Client.main(Client.java:20)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to create a bucket using **S3Client**.

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.waiters.WaiterResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.CreateBucketRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.HeadBucketRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.HeadBucketResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.waiters.S3Waiter;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
// snippet-end:[s3.java2.create_bucket_waiters.import]

/**
 * Before running this Java V2 code example, set up your development
 * environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For more information, see the following documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */

public class CreateBucket {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        final String usage = """

                Usage:
                    <bucketName>\s

                Where:
                    bucketName - The name of the bucket to create. The bucket name must be unique, or an error occurs.
                """;

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println(usage);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String bucketName = args[0];
        System.out.format("Creating a bucket named %s\n", bucketName);
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        createBucket(s3, bucketName);
        s3.close();
    }

    public static void createBucket(S3Client s3Client, String bucketName) {
        try {
            S3Waiter s3Waiter = s3Client.waiter();
            CreateBucketRequest bucketRequest = CreateBucketRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .build();

            s3Client.createBucket(bucketRequest);
            HeadBucketRequest bucketRequestWait = HeadBucketRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .build();

            // Wait until the bucket is created and print out the response.
            WaiterResponse<HeadBucketResponse> waiterResponse = s3Waiter.waitUntilBucketExists(bucketRequestWait);
            waiterResponse.matched().response().ifPresent(System.out::println);
            System.out.println(bucketName + " is ready");

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

If you intend to asynchronously create an Amazon S3 bucket using **CompletableFuture**, then use the S3AsyncClient, as illustrated in the following code example:

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3AsyncClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.CreateBucketRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.CreateBucketResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

/**
 * Before running this Java V2 code example, set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For more information, see the following documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */
public class CreateBucketAsync {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        final String usage = """

            Usage:
                <bucketName>\s

            Where:
                bucketName - The name of the bucket to create. The bucket name must be unique, or an error occurs.
            """;

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println(usage);
           System.exit(1);
        }

        String bucketName = args[0];
        System.out.format("Creating a bucket named %s\n",
                bucketName);

        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3AsyncClient s3AsyncClient = S3AsyncClient.builder()
            .region(region)
            .build();

        createBucket (s3AsyncClient, bucketName);
    }

    public static void createBucket( S3AsyncClient s3AsyncClient, String bucketName) {
        try {
            CreateBucketRequest bucketRequest = CreateBucketRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .build();

            CompletableFuture<CreateBucketResponse> futureGet = s3AsyncClient.createBucket(bucketRequest);
            futureGet.whenComplete((resp, err) -> {
                try {
                    if (resp != null) {
                        System.out.println(bucketName +" is ready~");
                    } else {
                        err.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } finally {
                    // Only close the client when you are completely done with it.
                    s3AsyncClient.close();
                }
            });
            futureGet.join();

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```